# Ran Android Studio from the command line and got some logs. Is something broken with my install?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I ran Android Studio with sudo from the command line. I didn't expect the logs I saw below. Is anything wrong with my install?

```
2015-08-04 06:53:16.236 studio[43582:4127132] Value of STUDIO_JDK: (null)
2015-08-04 06:53:16.257 studio[43582:4127147] fullFileName is: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2015-08-04 06:53:16.257 studio[43582:4127147] fullFileName exists: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2015-08-04 06:53:16.257 studio[43582:4127147] Value of STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS is (null)

2015-08-04 06:53:16.257 studio[43582:4127147] Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2015-08-04 06:53:16.258 studio[43582:4127147] Done
2015-08-04 06:53:16.258 studio[43582:4127147] Processing VMOptions file at /var/root/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio1.2/studio.vmoptions
2015-08-04 06:53:16.258 studio[43582:4127147] No content found
2015-08-04 06:53:16.258 studio[43582:4127147] Processing VMOptions file at 
2015-08-04 06:53:16.258 studio[43582:4127147] No content found
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties: 'java.endorsed.dirs' already defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, nothing is wrong. This is debug logging that could be used to diagnose certain kinds of issues.